# how to set width and height of alertbox?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I want to set the width and height of alert box ,i tried it by fixing the width and height but showing error ,and also i want to set the width and height as 100%
Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this code (taken from [this page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_19.html)):

```
            myAlert = Alert.show("Are you sure?", "Alert", Alert.OK | Alert.CANCEL);
            myAlert.height = 150;
            myAlert.width = 150;
```

Keep in mind that alert windows in Flex are not modal, so code written after displaying the dialog is executed immediately. That's why the above sample works. If you want to postpone executing your code until the user responded to the alert, then use event listeners [as described here](http://www.roseindia.net/flex/add-event-listener.shtml).

I would not recommend setting the width and height to 100%, because that's not the standard behaviour of message boxes. You should set them to a width and height of a maximum of 50% of your application. Larger message boxes will be looked at as pop-up windows and [you know what users do with unexpected pop-up windows](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990530.html).

Comment: This does not work. The Alert window stretches but the text component in the window itself does not, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: You're right, but the same thing goes for the browser's Alert dialogs. You can use \n to insert line breaks to your alert text manually. And if you don't know the alert text in advance to insert the line breaks, then you probably shouldn't to alter the width and height either to prevent the text from overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

```
myAlert = Alert.show("Are you sure?", "Alert", Alert.OK | Alert.CANCEL);
myAlert.height = 150;
myAlert.width = 150;
```